# Why $scope is null in controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, closures

I have the below view and a controller. I just wanted to inspect $scope object for two-way data-binding inside my ng-click handler (submitting the form) but it is always undefined.

Here is my view:

```
<body ng-controller="efController" class="container">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

And here is my controller:

```
app.controller("efController",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            //alert($scope.name);
        }
    }]);
```

If there is nothing inside my submitForm() function and I put a breakpoint on closing brace, the $scope is always undefined in the watch but if I simply write an alert or access any model property by using $scope.prop, it is always fine.

My question is why is it undefined when the function is being called properly and the $scope is also being injected?

**Edit:** here is the screenshot from video where the guy is inspecting $scope in watch and you can trust me my code is 200% same as his. And this is the link to course on pluralsight http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-forms-bootstrap-mvc5

[image]

**Edit 2:** Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oSsUHquukqoonXGWkdpM) John Papa.

Comment: Because that's how closures work. The scope variable will be available in your submitform function only if you use it inside that function. I'll let someone else expand on that if they want to.

Comment: @jlowcs Can you please explain a bit more? I have seen the same thing working in one of pluralsight's angular course.

Comment: Another short explanation tentative: in JS - that is not related to angular - every function execution creates a closure of all the variables used by this function. Since you commented `$scope.name`, $scope is not included in the `submitForm` closure, so you cannot see it when adding abreak point.

Comment: @jlowcs If you tell me its due to closure, then according to my simplest understanding of closures, any nested function can access variables of outer functions. Then how come $scope is undefined inside inner function? Please help me rectify my closure concept if im wrong here.

Comment: create a plunkr or codepen and we'll help debug

Comment: @Jay: Your understanding of closures is wrong. The presence of ``$scope`` in the ``submitForm`` function creates a closure where ``$scope`` is accessible from that function. If ``$scope`` is not present in that function, no closure is created, therefore ``$scope`` is not accessible from that function. Setting a breakpoint in the function just allows you to have a look at what's available in the function when it is executed. No closure, so ``$scope`` is not available.

Comment: As florbon said: "every function execution creates a closure of all the variables used by this function". $scope is not used by the function, thefore it is not in the closure.